# Boundary of a set in the one point compactification

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $V$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($n\geq1$) and $\overline{V}$ the closure of $V$. Let $W$ be the complement of $\overline{V}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}\cup\{\infty\}$ (one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$). What is the boundary of $W$? Is it equal to the boundary of $V$ or to the boundary of $V$ union $\{\infty\}$?

Comment: well, $\infty$ already belongs to $W$, since $\bar{V}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $W$ is the complement in the one-point compactification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $\partial V$ (the boundary of $V$). Since $V$ is bounded, $\infty$ does not belong to the closure of $V$ (in $\mathbb R^n\cup\{\infty\})$. And $\partial V=\partial\overline V=\partial\overline V^\complement=\partial W$,